# Set view in a middle of an other view in android xml

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml

Anyone know how to set a View (Button) in the middle of another View ? For example i want that the two Buttons on the top or adjust with the middle of the Button connexion. I presice that there is something in the left of my parent view so i cannot align with the layout, thanks 

what i have :

 [image]

what i want :

[image]

Comment: can you post your xml code?

Comment: can you clarify your question and post your xml as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place both buttons inside a `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout's` orientation should be `horizontal`. Give each button `layout_weight` of `1`. Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `android:gravity="center"`(or just `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on your demand) to its parent if you are using LinearLayout.

If you are using RelativeLayout, then you can set the view wherever you want by using `layout_alignParentBottom`, `layout_centerHorizontal`, ... and other attrs.

I am not very sure where do you want to put the two buttons at, please try above solutions and give more details (maybe your current xml) if it still can not be solved.